# Where clause in querybuilder and eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, query-builder

I've seen some code like this one below:

```
public function scopeUserId($query, $user_id)
{
   return $query->whereUserId($user_id);
}
```

Now, the question is what is whereUserId pertain(though it is verbose enough, but the syntax gets me confused) and where can I find it in the laravel documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that can be just another (bad-named) scope:

```
public function scopeWhereUserId($query, $user_id) {
    return $query->where("user_id", $user_id);
}

public function scopeUserId($query, $user_id) {
    return $query->whereUserId($user_id);
}

...

$roles = Roles::whereUserId($id);
$roles_flattened = Roles::userId($id)->flatten();
```

... or be some magic-extended substitution for query builder (or is it in built-in builder?):

```
class MyQueryBuilder extends QueryBuilder {
...

public function __call($method, $args) {
    if (Str::beginsWith($method, "where")) {
        $whereColumn = str_replace("where", "", $method);
        $whereColumn = camelCaseToSnakeCase($whereColumn);
        return $this->where($whereColumn, array_shift($args))
    }

    return parent::__call($method, $args)
}

...
}
```

**Upd: Indeed it is. Here is related `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class code:**

```
/**
 * Handle dynamic method calls into the method.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \BadMethodCallException
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (static::hasMacro($method)) {
        return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
    }

    if (Str::startsWith($method, 'where')) {
        return $this->dynamicWhere($method, $parameters);
    }

    $className = get_class($this);

    throw new BadMethodCallException("Call to undefined method {$className}::{$method}()");
}
```

Comment: thanks! I thought I got it when I read the dynamicWhere method :D